# IsDate("30/09/2017") returns false, but I don't know the format

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I'm reading data from CSV files that have been exported from Excel. I then parse the values into a standard format, basically some cleanup, and put it into the next column. To do this I use the VB functions like `IsNumeric` and `IsDate` to try to figure out what the data might be. This is working fine for numbers and such, but fails for dates. Here's some examples from a real data file I was handed:

```
200001
5/8/2014 0:00
30/09/2017 12:00:00 AM
2014-08-05
2017-09-30
04/06/2014 12:00:00 AM
30/06/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

And here's the results:

```
200001  1/1/2000
5/8/2014 0:00   5/8/2014
30/09/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/1/1900
2014-08-05  8/5/2014
2017-09-30  9/30/2017
04/06/2014 12:00:00 AM  4/6/2014
30/06/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/1/1900
```

So IsDate managed to understand "200001", "5/8/2014 0:00" and "04/06/2014 12:00:00 AM", but fails to understand the perfectly valid "30/09/2017 12:00:00 AM". I understand this is due to mm/dd vs dd/mm, but since I have no idea which one is being used, on a line-by-line basis, does anyone have a suggestion on how to handle this?

Following the suggestion below, I tried this:

```
Public Function IsDMYDate(input As String) As Boolean
    Dim TempD As DateTime
    Dim formats() As String = {"d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "d/M/yyyy h:mm tt",
                             "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss",
                             "d/M/yyyy hh:mm tt", "d/M/yyyy hh tt",
                             "d/M/yyyy h:mm", "d/M/yyyy h:mm",
                             "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm",
                            "d-M-yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "d-M-yyyy h:mm tt",
                             "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", "d-M-yyyy h:mm:ss",
                             "d-M-yyyy hh:mm tt", "d-M-yyyy hh tt",
                             "d-M-yyyy h:mm", "d-M-yyyy h:mm",
                             "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm"}
    Return DateTime.TryParseExact(input, formats, New CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, TempD)
End Function
```

but it returns false on these dates as well. Then I tried this, after looking up various CultureInfo settings:

```
Public Function IsDMYDate(input As String) As Boolean
    Dim TempD As DateTime
    Dim Local As CultureInfo
    'now try things...
    Local = New CultureInfo("en-US")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, TempD) Then
        Return True
    End If
    Local = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, TempD) Then
        Return True
    End If
    Local = New CultureInfo("en-AU")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, TempD) Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

It always returns false as well.

Comment: Various date formats are always fun to deal with.  You might want to create a helper function that uses `DateTime.TryParseExact` with the different formats you expect to see.  Ugly, but workable.

Comment: Those legacy VB functions (like `IsDate`) are (almost) universally aware of only the current culture.  If `30/09/2017` is not a valid format for your culture it will fail.

Comment: Gah! I guess I'm spoiled by unix.

Comment: @Tim any good examples? I tried the one on the MS page, but it still fails to parse it. Plutonix (can't @ you) 200001 is not valid in my culture either, but that one *is* working.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz - can you post an example of what you tried?  The examples on the MSN page are generally pretty good.

Comment: @Tim - added to original post

Comment: `IsDate` fails for me with both 200001 forms: https://ideone.com/gJR1w8

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Function IsDMYDate(input As String) As Boolean
    Dim TempD As DateTime
    Dim Local As CultureInfo
    'now try things...
    Local = New CultureInfo("en-US")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, Local, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, TempD) Then
        Return True
    End If
    Local = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, Local, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, TempD) Then
        Return True
    End If
    Local = New CultureInfo("en-AU")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, Local, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, TempD) Then
        Return True
    End If
    Local = New CultureInfo("fr-FR")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, Local, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, TempD) Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return False
End Function
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function DMYDate(input As String) As DateTime
    Dim TempD As DateTime
    Dim Local As CultureInfo
    'now try things...
    Local = New CultureInfo("en-US")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, Local, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, TempD) Then
        Return TempD
    End If
    Local = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, Local, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, TempD) Then
        Return TempD
    End If
    Local = New CultureInfo("en-AU")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, Local, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, TempD) Then
        Return TempD
    End If
    Local = New CultureInfo("fr-FR")
    If DateTime.TryParse(input, Local, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, TempD) Then
        Return TempD
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: This can fail for 11 dates in every month.  Given your date of  `5/8/2014` meaning Aug 5 (GB) it will validate as June 8 because it tests the US culture first.

Comment: Indeed, but that's not a failure, that's a design feature.